# Yamaha P2250 PA(A) Protection Issue

Tags: amplifier, circuit-protection

I have an old Yamaha P2250 having protection issue, after long troubleshooting, I found that there are DC voltages coming out from PA(A) output TP205

Base +/- 23 vDC and Emmitor +/- 23 vDC

Protection mode turned off when I disconnect +/- 15v that power up OP AMP or remove output jack from output board.

I don't understand what the issue is, can anyone please advise where should I look?

I have attached the service manual image of PA(A)

On RED It sensed 1.9 Voltages, protection mode turned off if I removed, Yellow Jack or the Green

---

**I got results here**

1. TP201 = 0v,
2. TP202 = 0v,
3. TP205 = 3v Neg,
4. TP206 = 0.001v,
5. TP203 = 3v Neg,
6. TP204 = 3v Neg,
7. IC201 = 9v Neg at Pin 1,
8. All output transistors BASE and Emmitor showing 3v Neg and Collector showing +/- 61v
9. When I disconnect +/-15v Jack that power up OP AMP, DCO removes from output TP205, 206

---

[image]

---

**My Problem has been Solved.**

I just re-solder all transistors that connected with the heat sink, and clean PCB and it's working fine.

Comment: What's a Yamaha P2250?

Comment: What does the Yellow Jack do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: DC Offset voltages are coming out from speaker output and amp switch into protect mode, all Base, Emmitor showing +/-3 Voltages DC

Comment: Yellow jack has +/- 15v that power up OP AMP IC 072

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Threshold for DC offset protection is +/-2V.

With all boards connected except protection and speakers;

Check DC offset from end to end in yellow for the channel affected.

- record results in question.  Some part has worn out and is causing the offset.

[See below](https://www.hifiengine.com/hfe_downloads/index.php?yamaha/yamaha_p1150_1250_2150_2250_service_en.pdf)
[image]

[image]

From results in Q, triage below.
[image]

The results indicate a negative voltage path fault due to a DC fault which could be any part in the front end, but is most likely the FET facing the input shorted , but shorted across Drain-Source. THe other side is for error correction and pin 1 has an error of 9V which is excessive and **means the correction has possibly failed in the differential FETs (Q201)** or less likely in the components that follow it above.  **This is also a very ESD-sensitive part but has some protection on board with C201. (caution when replacing Q201)**  detailed voltages on every pin of all parts around the FETs could confirm that, but **the best estimate is to replace Q201.**

Comment: results are in question.

Comment: Any idea if I didn't get those FETs so is there any other way to bypass it? because it's very old and might be not able to find here.

Comment: It's available everywhere including Ebay for this obsolete part and LTI has an improved new part.  It cannot be bipassed

Comment: I pull out that FET and tested it using multimeter, and its showing perfect, than I pull out other channel FET and installed on defective channel, DC voltages showing same and I put channel A mosfet to channel B and channel B working fine, it means no issue with FET, I pull out 072 ic and pin 1 showing 0 volts on IC, why I am getting higher DC voltages when i remove input signal wire